# Previsão de demanda para muitos itens

Tags: r, forecast

Boa tarde, pessoal. Gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês, sobre o seguinte:
Eu estou trabalhando em uma empresa e-commerce, que possui mais de 1000 itens a venda, sendo que cada item desse, possui uma série história de vendas diárias, de 2019 até hoje.
O desafio é fazer uma previsão de vendas para cada item, baseado no seu histórico de vendas passadas. Para tal, as dúvidas que eu tenho são as seguintes:

1- qual modelo utilizar?

2- qual software mais indicado para esta previsão? sendo que eu tenho mais de 1000 produtos, e sendo que para cada produto é uma série histórica diferente

3- Eu terei que fazer uma projeção para cada item? não vejo sentido nisso, pois o esforço seria tremendo, e demandaria muito tempo, mas se for este o caso, me digam!!

Obs: os dados estão contidos numa planilha do excel no seguinte formato: cada coluna é um SKU (produto) e cada linha é o número total de vendas daquele respectivo sku, e na respectiva data semanal.

Por favor se alguem que ja trabalhou com previsão de vendas em alguma empresa, me salvem!!! Ficarei grato.

Answer (score 0):

O processo de análise de séries temporais engloba testes de raiz unitária, sazonalidade, tendência, mas como são muitas séries temporais vou dar uma sugestão que provavelmente não daria em uma situação normal. Recomendo usar modelos univariados de séries temporais, eles usam o histórico da série para prever o comportamento dela mesma, a biblioteca `forecast` do R tem uma função `auto.arima` que busca o melhor modelo ARIMA minimizando um critério de informação a sua escolha.

Se você procurar sobre modelos ARIMA no R pode conseguir algumas informações sobre como fazer isso, mas acredito que estudar modelos univariados e a biblioteca `forecast`são um bom caminho e que a função `auto.arima` ajuda a poupar tempo algumas vezes.